# Use vba to trigger html anchor href="javascript:void(0)"

Tags: javascript, html, excel, vba

This is my first post ever, so I hope not to bore you.

I am trying to use excel vba to access this [website](https://www.eex-transparency.com/homepage/power/germany/production/usage/actual-unitwise-production-100-mw-) to get its data. I can get the data and I can change the dates, my problem is to change the times (e.g. 00:00 - 01:00 to 01:00 - 02:00). I guess this is due to the

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="select2-choice" tabindex="-1">
```

behind the element. 
I just don't understand how to pass on the new time-span and how to trigger it to change the data. I already tried "FireEvents ("onclick")" on the anchor element without success.

I hope anybody can help me. Thank you!!

Comment: Olease let me know if more information is needed to help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I already managed to change the time shown on the website element by using

```
Set myData10 = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("span")
For Each inputElement In myData10
    If inputElement.ID = "select2-chosen-3" Then
        Set timepicker = inputElement
        timepicker.Focus
        timepicker.innerText = "02:00 - 03:00"
     End If
Next
```

but it seems like the new time is still not processed by the website. The data on the website did not change to the new time.