# Impossible to trigger a javascript anchor with VBA

Tags: javascript, html, vba, excel

I am a newbie with VBA but with help from different websites and this one for which I am really grateful, I managed to put together a macro that will connect to a certain website and fill a menu with a value "Closed" then click on OK.

The problem is the value appears in the menu but it is as if it was not recognized as such. When OK is clicked it says that no value has been entered.

I figure there is something to do with the javascript:void(0)link inside but couldn't manage to find what exactly.

I figured my problem was related to this thread left unanswered: [Use vba to trigger html anchor href="javascript:void(0)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41263872/use-vba-to-trigger-html-anchor-href-javascriptvoid0)

Here is the HTML code :

```html
<div class="modal ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" id="pausingModal" scrolltop="0" scrollleft="0" style="width: auto; min-height: 0px; height: auto;"><label>Please specify the reason</label><div class="row"><div class="select2-container select2 reason select2-container-active select2-dropdown-open" id="s2id_autogen2" style="width: 100%"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="select2-choice select2-default" tabindex="-1">   <span class="select2-chosen" id="select2-chosen-3">Select a reason</span><abbr class="select2-search-choice-close"></abbr>   <span class="select2-arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span></a><label for="s2id_autogen3" class="select2-offscreen"></label><input class="select2-focusser select2-offscreen" type="text" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" aria-labelledby="select2-chosen-3" id="s2id_autogen3" disabled=""></div><select class="select2 reason select2-offscreen" style="width: 100%" tabindex="-1" title=""><option></option><optgroup label="Related"><option data-pause-type="hard_pause" data-show-text-area="false" value="1">Closed</option>
```

Here is the VBA code :

```
'Select the reason    For Each obj In objIE.Document.getElementsByTagName("span")
If obj.id = "select2-chosen-3" Then
obj.Focus
obj.innerText = "Closed"
Exit For
End If
Next

 ' Wait
Do While objIE.Busy = True
DoEvents
Loop
Do While objIE.readyState <> 4
DoEvents
Loop
Sleep 待ち時間
```

Up until here the value appears in the drop-down box. But it is as if the website doesn't recognize it as selected. I tried the following code to "trigger" the value without luck:

```
  'Trigger the value
For Each obj In objIE.Document.getElementsByTagName("a")
If obj.className = "select2-choice select2-default" Then
obj.Click
Exit For
End If
Next
```

Could someone point me in the right direction ?

Comment: It would be better if you share the website url

Comment: I know but its an internal URL, I tried to find similar cases on different website but there is no problem when Im trying to run this macro on them... Could it help if I put more of the HTML code ?

Comment: Anyone would have an idea ? I am really stuck here, been looking around all web to find a solution without success...

Answer (score 0):

So I tried to change my code to input the text instead of selecting it :

```
'Select the reason
    For Each obj In objIE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")
    If obj.id = "s2id_autogen3" Then
    obj.Focus
    obj.innerText = "Closed"
    obj.FireEvent ("onclick")
    Exit For
    End If
    Next
```

The text gets selected but still no luck with validating it. [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKubG.png)